# On-premises JWT solution for Implicit grant/flow

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory

Azure AD provides a facility for acquiring JWT from its AD Authentication servers.  This works well for authenticating Single Page Apps against a Web API, using ADAL and JWT libraries in both.

However, if your requirements are to achieve a solution that would allow the ADAL JWT authentication with an on-premises Token issuer, how can you achieve this without changing the JWT shape and authentication mechanism?

Do I need to rewrite the auth modules on both the API and the SPA to accommodate a different OpenAuth framework?  Or is there a solution that would allow me to reuse the same code and just point both the API and SPA to an on-premises token issuer?

Answer (score 0):

This solvable with ADFS, but requires some customization using ADFS interfaces to work for all endpoints, i.e. Native, Web and API